# Android application Centralised Database Query

Tags: java, android

I am creating android application for my college notifications, I want to all the students to use same database through internet.What should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple approach would be:

Host the database in a public server. Then fetch data from & post data to database via web services. (basically you will be creating your own api)

use that api from your android app.

Comment: will you please elaborate hosting database on public server

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.